# Troubles when installing Hep-math

Tags: linux, installation, makefile

I'm using Moba-Xterm terminal on windows. I'm trying to install hep math-1.4 using the PDF manual. I need to use prefix to send it to the right location but i don't know where to that right location is.

After downloading the package and extracting it on desktop i have to do the following;

```
./configure --prefix= something

make 

make install
```

So when I do prefix=Desktop I got an error?

Help to find a good prefix?
i'm new on linux

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a custom prefix if you run the last command as root:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Update: The next page of the manual says

> If you want to generate Python extension modules with HEPMath you may want to use
> a prefix that your Python interpreter searches for Python packages. On my system this
> is $HOME/.local.

Comment: I got this :
configure: error: in `/home/mobaxterm/Desktop/hepmath-1.4':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: »» no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH «« : Install the g++ compiler for your OS. I.e. g++ will also take care of installing the packages that make gcc functional.

Comment: I got this now:

configure: error: could not determine ar interface btw thank you for your help

Comment: @AbdelXY I don't think the comments are the proper place to debug the installation of a software package. Since the dependencies aren't listed in the manual, you may want to ask the authors directly and/or use `dnf whatprovides '*/command'` (or your distro's equivalent) to track down dependencies.